# Is there anyone who has successfully installed Selenium on iOS?

Tags: python, ios, selenium, webdriver, pythonista

I could install it using stash (“pip install selenium”) on iPhone but it doesn’t accept any webdriver.

Traceback error message:

"Exception: SafariDriver was not found; are you running Safari 10 or later? You can download Safari at https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/."

```html
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
URL = "http://edatai.us/blog/2012/11/20/placing-kpis-different-cron-schedules"

b = webdriver.Safari()
b.get(URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The WebDriver implementation for Safari is developed and maintained by Apple, and is designed to automate the desktop version of Safari. It is installed as part of the OS, and does not support mobile Safari on iOS at present. To automate mobile Safari, you can use a project like [Appium](http://appium.io/), which uses the Selenium API to control mobile apps and browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have installed Selenium on desktop (VSCode) and it works perfectly for browser automation.